# Multiple details in one report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have a sample output for Statement of Account report in excel but i don't know what approach will i use to deploy it using crystal reports. will i use 3 details section? 
The report has 3 parameters such as customer code, date range from and to. In addition
to this, it has 3parts with conditions of what details to display.

```
 (1) Previous Open transaction: all open transactions prior to selected date range
 (2) current Period: all transactions whether Open or close within selected date range 
 (3) Current Open transactions: All Open transaction as of today's date

any suggestion?
```

Comment: Does 3 parts are interrelated? or those are totally saperate and should be desiplayed individually?

Comment: Yes, i created just one VIEW for all the 3 parts then all data to be displayed in 3parts where coming to that VIEW, the difference is there are conditions to be passed to be able to display results.

Answer (score 0):

since you have created 1 view that has all the data..Below approach is useful to you:

1. Take a main report and in that 3 sub report.
2. Firs sub report take the view and create a parameter `?Previous Open transaction` and apply the same in `record sort expert` as

   ```
    databasefield.Previous Open transactio> ={?Previous Open transaction}
   ```
3. Second sub report take the same view and create a parameter `?current Period` and apply the same in `record sort expert`

   ```
   dataabsefield.current period={?current Period}
   ```
4. Third sub report take the same view and create a parameter `?Current Open transactions` and apply the same in `record sort expert`

   ```
   databasefield.Current Open transactions={?Current Open transactions}
   ```
5. Now in main report create these 3 parameters and link the sub reports as per the parameters of indivdual sub reports.
6. Place the fields in the sub reports as per your requirement.

Comment: thanks for this, ill give it a try and let you know the results

Comment: sorry, i need to enter this formula "dataabsefield.current period={?current Period}" to the record sort expert??

Comment: Yes.. enter in `record sort expert`

Comment: Sorry. can u explain it to me more detailed?? i dont know how to do it :(